# Manually calling a decorator that takes arguments

Tags: python, decorator

I have a function f1:

```
def f1():
  return True
```

I also have a decorator that takes arguments, that can be used like this:

```
@validate_arguments(arg1, arg2)
```

I am trying to call `f1` manually without the `@` (for testing and reuse purposes) but that doesn't seem to work.

So something like:

```
validate_arguments(f1, arg1, arg2)
```

The reason it does not work is because `validate_arguments` is a function that takes the arguments as parameters, and contains a closure that is the actual decorator.

Is there no way to do what I want? To manually call the decorator on a function without the `@`, for a decorator that takes arguments?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need something like:

```
def f1():
  return True
f1 = validate_arguments(arg1, arg2)(f1)
```

Here `validate_arguments(arg1, arg2)` returns the actual decorator, to that decorator we pass the function object `f1`, which in turn returns the new modified function.

**Demo:**

```
def validate_arguments(arg1, arg2):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapped():
            print arg1, arg2
            return func()
        return wrapped
    return decorator

def f1():
  return True
f1 = validate_arguments(1, 2)(f1)
print f1()
#1 2
#True
```

Comment: Slightly related: if you want to call a decorator without passing in a function (e.g. the decorator does its work in the global scope): `the_decorator(lambda: None)()`

Comment: When f1 is a function with arguments, eg. f1(argX, argY), then the manually decorated function would be defined like this:
manually_decorated_f1 = validate_arguments(1, 2)(lambda: f1(3, 4))
where 3 and 4 are the values of argX and argY.